# Proving a parabola and polynomial intersect exactly 3 times

Tags: calculus, rolles-theorem

the equations are : $P(x)=5-8(x-1)^2$ for the parabola and the other equation is $E(x)=(x-1)^5$ we need to prove that they intersect exactly 3 times.

What I did was compare them at first  $5-8(x-1)^2 = (x-1)^5 $ and then make a new function $f(x)$ according to that we get $f(x)=(x-1)^5 -5+8(x-1)^2$and the function is continuous because its a polynomial and we can also have a derivative.
I tried applying some numbers and i got $f(-1)=-5$ , $f(0)=2$ , $f(-5)=-7493$ , $f(2)=4$  so according to the Intermediate value theorem we have **at least** 3 roots but what we need to prove is that it has **exactly** 3 roots. and this looked like rolle's theorem

What I tried then was we want to show that it has exactly 3 roots according to Rolle's theorem so if the original equation has 4 roots the first derivative needs to have exactly 3

$f'(x)=5(x-1)^4 +16(x-1)$

And I got stuck here I could not figure a way to continue from here ..

Thanks for any tips and help all is appreciated and I would also like to know if anyone can confirm that what I did was right until the last step.

Sorry for my english mistakes hope it is understandable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ Q = E-P = (x-1)^5 -5 + 8(x-1)^2$$

By descartes rule of signs, for the positive 'x' values this polynomial has a maximum of two real roots or no real roots.

Now shift $ x \to -x$

$$Q(-x) = -(x+1)^5 -5 + 8 (x+1)^2$$

By descartes rules of sign it has maximum of one roots for negative $x$ side

So, combining the two ideas, we get that it should have either one or three roots. Now, since you've identified existence of the three roots, this means the polynomial has only three real roots.

Answer (score 2):

shifting the origin :$x-1=t$ we have to find the number of roots of $$f(t)=t^5-8t^2+5=0=(t-a)(t-b)(t-c)(t-d)(t-e)$$ here $a,b,c,d,e$ are its roots.Also one can evaluate $$a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+e^2=0$$
which is not possible unless  atleast one is complex or all are zero(which in this case is impossible)  ; WLOG $e$ be complex then by $a+b+c+d+e=0$  we must have some other root must alos be complex hence $f(t)$ has minimum of of two complex roots, you have already found 3 real roots so...

---

by comparing coefficients:
$s=a+b+c+d+e=0$
$$w=ab+ac+ad+ae+bc+bd+be+cd+ce++de=0$$
also $$s^2-2w=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+e^2$$
hence $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+e^2=0$

Comment: much appreciated for the amazing way that I wouldn't be close to think about. canyou pleass explain the first step ? you took the $(t-a)(t-b)(t-c)(t-d)(t-e)$ as it has 5 roots right ? but how did you apply vietas formulas here ? thank you

Comment: @Adamrk see edit

Comment: "which is possible when atleast one is complex" shouldn't ti be "not possible"

Comment: @Buraian It is not possible **unless** at least one is complex or they are all zero. But it is possible when at least one is complex. Surely in the end we conclude that at least one **is** complex and its complex conjugate is also a root.

Comment: @Buraian i dont understand,

Comment: I was mistaken but I understood when @DavidK had pointed out. A small minor note is that directly calling that modified vieta as vieta may cause confusion

Comment: Thank you all for the amazing help ! both answers are great still struggling a bit to understand the vieta formula part but I appreciate the help! will try harder to understand it

Comment: @Adamrk i have avoided vieta and indtead used just comparing coefficeints

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore had my mind locked on the vieta part my bad just found it very interesting as i studied that in high school and now i see it again , it is also understandable with the coefficients thank you !

Comment: @Adamrk you are welcome!